ComposeView .setContent{} is being skipped !!! Even ComposeView is not null
i have a contraint layout which has a composeview but when i try setContent that part gets skipped code and logs before and after that is being executed
container?.apply {
   Log.d("DSM","APPLY")
   setContent {
      Log.d("DSM","SET CONTENT")
      detailsScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
      DetailsScreen(detailsScreenViewModel = detailsScreenViewModel) 
   }
}


Can you please add more content as this could be because of several factors?

Container is Composeview  which is not null i have checked and since the code has lot of extra stuff i cant put it here

`fun initialise(){
Log.d("DSM","initliasing scene vm")
Log.d("DSM","${container == null}")
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        Log.d("DSM", "Inside Handler Lopper")
        container?.setContent {
            Log.d("DSM", "Inside setContent on Main Thread")
            Text("Hello from Main Thread!")
        }
    }

}`
i Even Added this handler loopert  but  this also gets blocked i dont get log which is inside handler looper too

Issue got solved
